# How can I report an incorrect response from my Google Home?

Tags: google-home

Sometimes, my Google Home gets a little confused and completely misinterprets what I've asked (and it seems other people get the same problem quite often).

For example, the assistant [thinks Home Alone is "everything wrong with Deadpool in 15 minutes or less"](https://www.reddit.com/r/googlehome/comments/5l3tyo/ok_google_play_everything_wrong_with_deadpool_in/), [just gives up sometimes when things go wrong](https://www.reddit.com/r/googlehome/comments/5ekt5o/sorry_something_went_wrong_when_youre_ready_give/) and [can't read calendars correctly](https://www.reddit.com/r/googlehome/comments/5gvw22/calendar_is_wrong/).

Obviously, when things go wrong, it'd be nice if the developers would fix the issue, so I'd like to know if it's possible to report a specific conversation as incorrect or broken, so that they can sort it out.

**Is there any way I can alert the Google developers if I come across any bad behaviour, so that they can fix the issue?** Is this even necessary at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since no one is taking this one on, I'll take a shot at it.  :)

**Android Google Home App**: *If* you have the Android Google Home app, *then* follow [these steps](https://support.google.com/googlehome/answer/7071494):

1. Make sure you're on the same wifi as your Google Home and open the Android app.
2. Go to the hamburger menu, and go to `Help & Feedback` > `Submit Feedback Report` (bottom of screen)
3. Select the device you've had an issue with
4. Select your correct e-mail address
5. Write up your report!  Include your e-mail address and relevant keywords.
6. Check the "Include screenshot and logs" box.
7. Submit!

**Iphone & Ipad**: (I'll just quote from [the same Google Support page](https://support.google.com/googlehome/answer/7071494)):

> - Make sure your mobile device or tablet is connected to the same Wi-Fi as your Google Home device.
> - Open the Google Home app .
> - In the top left corner of the Home screen, tap Menu  and then Feedback.
> - Tap the device you'd like to submit feedback for.
> - In the feedback summary, write a brief description of your issue. Please include any important keywords.
> - Be sure to check the boxes next to "Include system data" and "Include Google Account".
> - Tap Preview in the bottom right corner to review your feedback.
> - Tap Send in the bottom right corner to submit feedback.

**But... there's more.**

Of course, Google Home being what it is, you ought to be able to send feedback via voice, oughtn't you?  The answer is yes.  You should be able to... and you can!  Simply say the following:

```
Ok, Google  [or, Hey, Google]
```

then

```
Send Feedback.
```

And now you can fire away your bug or feedback report *by voice.*